# Why does storing a local variable and reading it back trigger a TargetInvocationException?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, cil, reflection.emit

Let's suppose I have this method:

```
MethodBuilder doubleMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Double", 
                                                     MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static,
                                                     typeof(int), new [] { typeof(int) });
ILGenerator il = countMethod.GetILGenerator();

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);  // We load the input argument (an int) into the evaluation stack
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2); // We load the integer 2 into the evaluation stack
il.Emit(OpCodes.Mul);      // We multiply both numbers (n * 2)
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);      // We return what is left on the evaluation stack, i.e. the result of the multiplication
```

I can call this method successfully:

```
Type type = typeBuilder.CreateType();
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("Double");
object result = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { 4 }); // result = 8
```

However, If I change my IL code to this:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);  // We load the input argument (an int) into the evaluation stack
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2); // We load the integer 2 into the evaluation stack
il.Emit(OpCodes.Mul);      // We multiply both numbers (n * 2)

/* I added these two instructions */
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);  // We pop the value from the evaluation stack and store into a local variable
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);  // We read that local variable and push it back into the evaluation stack

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);      // We return what is left on the evaluation stack, i.e. the result of the multiplication
```

When trying to call the generated method, the following exception is thrown:

> TargetInvocationException was unhandled - Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Why is this? I mean, popping the value from the evaluation stack and then pushing the same value again should do absoultely nothing. By the time it reaches `OpCodes.Ret`, the correct value should be on the evaluation stack.

Comment: Before you get hot and heavy into this, first understand how to diagnose a TargetInvocationException.  You *have* to look at the InnerException to find out what went wrong.  And use ILGenerator.DeclareLocal() so it can properly measure the required stack size.

Comment: @HansPassant Actually, the inner exception just states `"Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program"`, I thought it was too generic to find it relevant, and the stack trace seems of no help either.

Comment: @HansPassant Adding `il.DeclareLocal(typeof(int))` did the trick! Thank you! May you post it as an anwer? (Also, why do I need to call this method?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a local variable in IL, you first need to *declare it*, so that the runtime knows its type. To do that, use [`ILGenerator.DeclareLocal()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1xffef4).

You might also consider [using the `LocalBuilder` returned from `DeclareLocal()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2725z44) when emitting instructions that use the variable. This way, you don't need to remember the indexes of all your local variables:

```
var local = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));

…

il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, local);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, local);
```